# Sudoku Solver, check each 3x3 box

Tags: matlab

To sum my problem up in a nutshell, I am checking each 3x3 box if there is one missing value, if there is, it computes what that number is, and then fills that number in. However, it only does the upper left 3x3 box, and stops there. Here is the snippet of my code that relates to my issue. If you'd like to see the rest of the code just ask and I'll post the rest.

EDIT: The user inputs the board. For test purposes I tried inputting a completed Sudoku puzzle, and then take out the top right value in each box. It only filled in the first 3x3, it still output the board at the end, but had 8 other blanks to fill in (from the other 8 3x3 boxes)

```
% Check each 3x3 box for one through nine, fill in
for i = 0:2
    for j = 0:2
        if sum(sum(board([1:3]+i*3,[1:3]+j*3)~=0))==8
            [row,col] = find(board([1:3]+i*3,[1:3]+j*3)==0);
            answer = 45 - sum(sum(board([1:3]+i*3,[1:3]+j*3)));
            board(row,col) = answer;
        end
    end
end
disp(board);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close. The problem is that for each block you are getting the row and column index of the **3x3** block. So, for each block the following is true: `row <= 3` and `col <= 3`.

You can easily solve this by adding these two lines after the line where you use `find`:

```
row = row + (3*i);
col = col + (3*j);
```

This way you convert the block-relative index back to the board-relative index.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I looked past that. Thank you very much! You've been a huge help. Tested that block and working as intended :)